# How can I turn input type="tel" into a variable with a number?

Tags: javascript

I want a user to input a number into `input type="tel"` or `type="number"` and then to make a variable with this number for further calculations. So far it is unable to identify a number. Any ideas?

```js
function digit() {
    var num = document.getElementById('inpt');
    document.body.innerHTML = num;
}
```

```html
<input onchange="digit()" type="tel" name="numb" id="inpt" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Set an event listener to changes of this input, then update the value of variable as it is mentioned above

Comment: Telephone numbers, despite the name, aren't *numbers*. They're strings. Don't tell me my mobile is `7712345678`. It's `07712 345 678`. My work number may well be `020 1234 5678 ext. 10`. Or `1 (408) 555-1234`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<script>
function digit() {
    var num = document.getElementById('inpt').value;
    document.body.innerHTML = num;
}
</script>
```

if it's not correct try this

```
console.log(document.getElementById('inpt'))
```

and show the object in browser console